# Model members value not updated

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new to asp.mvc and I'm trying to figure out why when I try to update values of a model through EditorFor helpers it won't send the updated value.

I have to follow a strict code convention and my parameters must start with a prefix (bln/str/int and so on)

If I leave the other parameters (permissionKey/stationKey/username) without the prefix, the values received are the updated one (the ones I need).

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Save")]
public ActionResult Save(int intId, string permissionKey, string stationKey, string username)
{
    var perm = _repository
        .Get(row => row.Id == intId)
        .First();

    perm.PermissionKey = permissionKey;
    perm.StationKey = stationKey;
    perm.Username = username;
```

If I change the definition to strPermissionKey/strStationKey/strUsername, I will receive the old values of the model.

Model:

```
public class EditablePermissionRowModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PermissionKey { get; set; }
    public string StationKey { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public bool EditPressed { get; set; } = false;
}
```

my Html looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Permissions"))
{

@*@Html.AntiForgeryToken()*@
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
.... more html....
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
        </button>
```

I also tried to include all parameters that I need as hidden.
    @Html.Hidden("strPermissionKey", Model.PermissionKey);

But this still didn't work. (Also tried @Html.Editor("strPermissionKey", Model.PermissionKey) but not luck)

What am I missing?

EDIT: 
@StephenMuecke helped and pointed out that I only need to pass the model back as a parameter... and this did it. Problem solved.

this: 
   public ActionResult Save(EditablePermissionRowModel udtModel) {
   ... code ....

Comment: What is the point of adding all those route values in your `BeginForm()` - none of them match your parameter  names, and if they did it would just send back the original model values. And why do you only have hidden inputs - what is the point of this if your passing back the identical values that you just sent to the view. Your view is based on a model, so your POST method just needs one parameter which is your model.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I forgot to delete the FormPost and those parameters. I use another overload. I was just trying to show that I already tried other alternatives

Comment: I'll try and use the model as the parameter. thank you!

Comment: @StephenMuecke Using the model as a parameter did it for me, can you please add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I don't even know what your model is - you did not show it :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I added the model as well. Thanks for the pointers, it helped. After i passed the model to the my save method, I got it working correctly. Thank you!

Comment: I think is a bit off-topic but you should ditch repositories and learn EF, when I started to learn MVC first thing I found was repositories and I haven't found that practice helpful at all, maybe it was an MVC 3 thing, I joined the mvc train only with version 5. Just to be on topic, do you save changes in database? Have you tried to put checkpoints on your fetch variables? to see exactly where desired information is lost?